# TypeError at /accounts/register/ __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

When trying to register a user with the custom user model in Django 2.0, I get the following error.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register/

Django Version: 2.0.5
Python Version: 3.6.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'crispy_forms',
 'homepage',
 'account']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\mittr\Desktop\MLASSI~1\mom\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\mittr\Desktop\MLASSI~1\mom\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\mittr\Desktop\MLASSI~1\mom\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mittr\Desktop\MLASSI~1\mom\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mittr\Desktop\ML Assignments\mom\src\account\views.py" in dispatch
  39.             return super(RegisterView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mittr\Desktop\MLASSI~1\mom\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mittr\Desktop\MLASSI~1\mom\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get
  168.         return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mittr\Desktop\MLASSI~1\mom\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get
  133.         return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())

File "C:\Users\mittr\Desktop\MLASSI~1\mom\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get_context_data
  66.             kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()

File "C:\Users\mittr\Desktop\MLASSI~1\mom\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get_form
  33.         return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())

Exception Type: TypeError at /accounts/register/
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'
```

#### Urls.py

```
path('register/', RegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
```

#### views.py

```
class RegisterView(CreateView):
    form_class = UserRegistrationForm
    template_name = 'registration/register.html'
    success_url = '/'

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('/login')
        else:
            return super(RegisterView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

#### Forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Email'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Email'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'full_name']

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match.")
        else:
            return password2

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        qs = User.objects.get(email__iexact=email)
        if qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("A user with this email already exists.")
        else:
            return email

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserRegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        user.is_active = False

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

### Other Information

I went on to `C:\Users\mittr\Desktop\ML Assignments\mom\Lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py` and I saw that line 33 has the following:

```
`return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())`
```

When I changed this to `return form_class()`, the registration page showed up successfully. However, I believe this is not the best way to go about doing business.

Also, the save() method in the forms.py file never got executed and hence the user was never saved in the custom user model. Any help with this will be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view is set to use UserRegistrationForm, but your form is UserRegisterForm.

Presumably, UserRegisterForm is a separate form which is not a modelform and which does not have a custom save method. You should change your view to point to the right form.